# Иностранные слова: развитие или уродование языка?

Tags: нормы-языка

Честно говоря, не помню, обсуждалось тут это уже или нет. Но все же спрошу.
Сейчас в речи молодежи постоянно слышны американизмы (я сейчас не говорю о, например, компьютерных терминах, которые не имеют аналогов в русском языке). Например, редко уже услышишь русской "ой", а сплошь и рядом восклицают уродливое "ауч" и т.д.
Как вы считаете, это нормальное развитие языка или его уродование? И что с этим можно сделать?
Благодарю.

Comment: "сплошь и рядом уродливо восклицают..." + "Как вы считаете, нормально это или уродливо?"

=>

Напоминает старый анекдот: "Уж не в амперах ли измеряется сила тока?" (мы типа тут все тупые)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использование  иноязычной  лексики  присуще  любому  языку  и  это  -  развитие.  Злоупотребление  этим  явлением  -  как  в  приведённом  примере - уродование.

Comment: Как вы определили, что в приведённом примере - злоупотребление?

Comment: Зачем  же  в  область  междометий  вторгаться ?  Здесь  нет  никаких  новых  понятий,  никаких  терминов,  которых  проще  усвоить  и  использовать,  чем  переводить.

Comment: Вы считаете, что язык меняется сознательно - посидел, подумал, поискал подходящее слово в иностранном языке?.. Да, так, наверное, тоже бывает. 

Но чаще всего никто никуда намеренно не вторгается; это как ветер (или дух святой... гм, ну, более-менее святой) - гуляет, где хочет: понравилось чужое слово - использовал, второй раз использовал - уже мода пошла, привычка...

Уродливо или нет получается - это дело вкуса и уместности (контекста), и я обычно остерегаюсь здесь давать оценки вне конкретной ситуации.

Comment: Нет,  я  не  думаю,  что  язык  меняется  сознательно.  Иноязычные  слова  появляются  по  необходимости  и  закрепляются  если  пришлись  ко  двору.  И  модные  веяния  тоже  имеют  место.  А  мода  сама  по  себе  штука  очень  не  однозначная.  Тут  сознательность  не  помешала  бы.  А  оценку  я  даю  в  контексте  заданного  вопроса.

Comment: В заданном вопросе никак не описан контекст. Просто кто-то русскоязычный сказал "ауч!". И участник @Noble (по каким-то неизвестным нам причинам) дал оценку ситуации как "уродливой". Вы тоже отказались раскрыть причину присоединения к оценке @Noble.

Да. А рядом со мной кое-кто постоянно _очень мило_, тоненьким, мелодичным голосом восклицает "ауч, бл...!". И мне приятно, и я даю ситуации оценку "отлично".

Comment: Ну, ситуацию  в  вашем  примере  я  бы  расценил  как  двойное  уродство.

Answer (score 0):

Кстати, для автора вопроса: "честно говоря" употреблять не следует.Лучше сказать "откровенно говоря".

Comment: Ответ подследственного следователю на допросе: "Честно говоря, я не знал, что у него в кармане был нож". Или всё-таки: "откровенно говоря"?

Comment: Если мы употребляем "честно говоря", это означает, что в остальных случаях мы говорим нечестно.

Comment: Если мы говорим "откровенно говоря", это означает, что в остальных случаях мы говорим неоткровенно. Хрен редьки не слаще!

Comment: Позвольте с Вами не согласиться.
 "Честно" и "откровенно" - две большие разницы, как говорят у них в Одессе.

Comment: Позвольте с Вами согласиться, что "честно" и "откровенно" - две разницы даже у нас, а не только у них в Одессе, но в таком случае - о чём мы спорим?